# how do i search for symbols in xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

In XCode 3 I was able to right click an Objective-C method name and choose to search for that method's symbol, so that I could see where it was defined and also where it was called in my codebase.  After upgrading to XCode 4, i can no longer do this.  Symbol search is also not available in the find options.  Is it possible to easily find where a method is used in addition to where a method is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as noted find where symbols are defined, but currently there's no way to specifically limit a search to used symbols.  You can use regular expressions in searches now which may help limit results if there are too many, or also use the filter bar at the bottom of the Search Navigator to limit results to some other criteria in addition to your search.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks.  I'd hoped the functionality was hidden away somewhere; I've no idea why apple would remove such a useful feature.

Comment: Me either - please file a radar on this as I found it useful too.  I think it was just something overlooked, or perhaps they thought people did not use it.

Comment: wtf? I was expecting better search features, and they removed it instead!!

Answer (score 3):

You can at least use the Open Quickly dialog `CMD+SHIFT+O` to easily open the symbol definition. This one lets you type in something like `initWithArg:andSomeOtherArg:` which I find easier than creating regular expressions for every method. But still I am also missing the Xcode 3 feature that allowed for searching for code that accesses a symbol.

Answer (score 2):

In the XCode 4 main editor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>,t hen type something and you will see it. If you want to search files like that, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can still go to the definition through the context menu (Jump to Definition). The default short-cut for this is Ctrl-Cmd-D.

To find where a method is used, use Search Navigator. Cmd-3 is the default short-cut to switch to Search Navigator. Here, you can make a search with various options.

Comment: The search navigator doesn't let me search for symbols though, like xcode 3 does.  if i want to search for all instances of the presentModalViewController:animated: method in my code in terms of actual method calls, i cannot.

Comment: Doesn't it make a textual search throughout the whole project? Click on the arrow beside the search icon and choose 'show search options'

Comment: Textual search works to a degree, however I would need to write a regular expression that can match all possible arguments passed into the method i mentioned before (or any method that takes 2 or more args) which I would rather not do.